# MVC. Где вызывать контроллеры, которым не нужен url?

Tags: php, mvc, controller

Запутался в MVC. У меня есть роуты вида

```
'news' => 'news/index',
```

Роутер, если роут найден, подключает необходимый контроллер и выполняется нужный экшен

**NewsController**

```
/**
 * Get all news
 */
public function actionIndex()
{
    $newsList = News::getNewsList();
    require_once(ROOT . '/views/news/index.php');

    return true;
}
```

А если мне нужны комментарии к новости, получается, что мне, вроде как, нужно сделать CommentsController, но где его потом вызывать? Тогда проще обращаться сразу к модели, но это уже что-то не то, как мне кажется

Comment: Создаете свой класс CommentsController. И Вызываете его в NewsController

Comment: не самая лучшая идея, тогда коментс лучше выводить в модуль и вызывать модуль, а не с одного контроллера вызывать другой

Comment: @SviatVolkov я так сразу и сделал, но это совсем плохая идея получилась

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если комментарии выводятся на странице новости - то и получать их нужно в контроллере новостей. Это абсолютно логично и оправдано.